# Ansible destination /etc is not writable

Tags: ansible

I'm getting an error that says `'destination /etc not writable'` when I run my playbook:

```
fatal: [B-mmp-edge-90c9.stg01.aws.company.net]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "checksum": "686f224b9b97fe890014e1320f48d31cae90abc2", "msg": "Destination /etc not writable"}
fatal: [B-mmp-edge-9df4.stg01.aws.company.net]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "checksum": "23cd3c17b1f9f84d48dc67affd5d3f4e09506b48", "msg": "Destination /etc not writable"}
```

My playbook `common.yml` just has this in it:

```
---
- hosts: all, !ansible
  roles:
    - common
```

And in `roles/common/meta/main.yml` I have:

```
---
dependencies:
  - { role: selinux_disable }
#  - { role: iptables_disable }
  - { role: motd }
  - { role: ntp }
#  - { role: epel }
#  - { role: hosts }
  - { role: users }
#  - { role: limits }
#  - { role: sysctl }
  - { role: snmp }
```

I'm using Ansible version 2.6.4.

I think I need to have root privileges. But I don't know how to do that in an Ansible role. Can somebody help with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To execute Ansible tasks with root privileges, you would need to add the following:

```
name: YourPlaybookName
hosts: YourHosts
become: yes
```

Note the third line and the `become: yes` directive.

For more information about privilege escalation in Ansible, please take a look at: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html